# Another way to debug an android app

Tags: android, debugging, testing

I want to debug my android application, I have Eclipse Installed fully setup for android developement.

The problem is,

1) I can't run android emulator(Hardware Concerns).

2) I can't attach phone to my computer(Driver Concerns).

Now,
Is there a way to get debug functionality by putting directly the apk into the phone storage and installing it from there.

I wanted get the logcat of the application that I'll be running.

Basically I'm quite naive in android, I'm not quite sure of the terms I said but, What I want is a way to test my app on my phone without the role of my PC.

Comment: Install adb drivers from adbdrivers.com iy will detect automatically and install working adb drivers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root you can use [Wifi ADB](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb&hl=ru)

Also you can remove drivers for this device and install other driver from your device manufacturer.

If you can run standard emulator you can use Genymotion.

Comment: Although it's wireless, there's still role of computer.